# 100 Base T vs 10G Base -T

Tags: networking

If I have a network of 300 workstations and they were all connected using 100 Base-T and a few workstations/a segment of the network were installed with 10G Base-T, however after the installation of the powerful workstation, they weren't able to connect/had network access problem. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

- Your newer network gear has to be able to automatically negotiate speed down to 100 MBit, which not every device is able to. Check packaging/documentation for infos on that.
- If it is able, it might mis-negotiate, possibly because the old gear doesn't negotiate at all (fixed speed). This may even happen between devices which are properly able to auto-negotiate on both sides. The only way out of this is to manually set the speed on the interface, if the device supports that. If not, your hardware is just incompatible with each other.